# Does anyone know a program or online service that allows to create an XML with given xs:schema?

Tags: xml, schema

Does anyone know a program or online service that allows to create an XML with given xs:schema?

Comment: Visual studio can be used for that

Comment: Thank you! But... It's pretty large... )) I do not use it... Maybe, there is something lighter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3645/A-Dynamically-Generated-XML-Data-Editor

I remember most of the commercial XML editors were not really light.